# bbpress Not Showing: How to troubleshoot?

Tags: bbpress

BBPress isn't showing on the front-end in a custom theme I've built and I can't figure it out.  I activated TwentyTwelve and it shows, so I know it's not a plugin.  I also cleared out functions.php and that didn't have any impact.  How do I begin troubleshooting from here?

Comment: Where doesn't it "show"? Back-end? Front?

Comment: Front end.  It shows in the back end.

Comment: We need more info than that. How are you trying to show it? Are you using the short code? How about showing the contents of your template files?

Comment: +1 Without seeing some of the code, or debug information, it's really hard to guess what might be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "most" stripped-down theme I can think of that can run **BBPress** is just a single `index.php` file containing:

```
<?php
// get_header();
if ( have_posts() ) : 
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
        the_content();
    endwhile; 
else : 
    _e( 'Nothing!' ); 
endif;
// get_footer();
?>
```

So my guess is that your `while` loop is missing something or you are overwriting the `the_content` filter used by BBPress!

Well, taking the extreme, it looks like it's possible to run it with the following one-liner in `index.php`:

```
<?php the_post(); the_content(); ?>
```

but that's just for fun ;-)